# convert string format 00:00:00,000 to milliseconds - python

Tags: python, datetime, time

I want to convert from string audio timestamps to milliseconds.

Sample Strings
00:00:16,260
00:00:26,339
00:19:38,769

Comment: The title makes no sense. The answer is 0.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Can you add some examples in form *input - desired output* pairs?

Comment: @roganjosh title is generalized 00:19:38,769 (XX:XX:XX,XXX) Editing the question to make it more sensible.

Comment: It really isn't so hard. You could use a regex or split around `':'` and `','`. Once you have 4 substrings, convert them to integers, multiply seconds by 1000, minutes by 60*1000, hours by 3600*1000, and add them all.

Comment: @EricDuminil Tried to cast it as Datetime object using strptime but getting this error `ValueError: unconverted data remains: :00:16,260`.

Comment: @AmeerHamza: Please show the code, even if it isn't working, and people will help you.

Comment: @EricDuminil Trying the regex, but wanted to know any cleaner way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assuming you want total milliseconds from the string.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

audio_timestamp = '00:00:16,260'
(datetime.strptime(audio_timestamp+'000', '%H:%M:%S,%f') - datetime.strptime('00', '%H')).total_seconds()*1000
```

gives 16260

Comment: Nice! It seems to work fine and doesn't depend on current date.

Answer (score 1):

You could split the string, convert to integers and assign to variables:

```
def timestamp_to_milliseconds(timestamp):
    hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds = [int(x) for x in timestamp.replace(',', ':').split(':')]
    return milliseconds + 1000 * (seconds + 60 * (minutes + 60 * hours))
```

Here's an example:

```
timestamp_to_milliseconds('00:19:38,769')
# 1178769
timestamp_to_milliseconds('00:00:16,260')
# 16260
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you need that but here is the solution of what I learned:

```
timestamp = "00:00:16,260".split(":")

seconds= float(timestamp[2].replace(',', "."))
minutes = int(timestamp[1])
hours = int(timestamp[0])

milliseconds= seconds*1000 + minutes*60*1000 + hours*3600*1000
```

Comment: @EricDuminil yes

Comment: It still isn't working because `'16,260'` doesn't look like a float. Also, it would be better to only work with integers

Comment: Why do it will be better to use only integers ?

Comment: Because milliseconds is now `16260.000000000002`, which is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that all values are properly padded with zeros then you can simply use indexing following way

```
t = "00:00:26,339"
h,m,s,ms = map(int,[t[:2],t[3:5],t[6:8],(t[9:]+"000")[:3]])
tms = h*60*60*1000+m*60*1000+s*1000+ms
print(tms) # prints 26339
```

Keep in mind that this solution assumes `t` is properly formatted.
EDIT: Improved to also accept string in form of 00:00:00